# Pass props from a Component to another Component on React

Tags: reactjs, state, google-signin

I've made a Login from `react-google-login`. I need to pass the email from one Component called `Login` to a second Component called `User` (where the user should see his email).

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      redirecting: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const responseGoogleSuccess = (response) => {
      this.setState({ email: response.profileObj.email });
      this.setState({ redirecting: true });
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleLogin
          clientId="myclientid"
          buttonText="Log in"
          onSuccess={responseGoogleSuccess}
          cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        />
        {this.state.redirecting ? <Redirect to="/user" /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use redux, or simpler, although not entirely secure, you could redirect using `/user?email=user@example.com` and grab it from the params in the user component.

Comment: Are you talking about https://redux.js.org/?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have so many ways to solve this issue.

1.`<Redirect to={/user/${this.state.email}} />`

you can access this email in user component using this.props.match.params.email

2.you can store email in redux store and access in user component.

3.you can use context api.

Comment: Could you explain me how to use redux store?

Comment: 1.you need create redux state variable for email.
2.you can change that varible by triggering action.
3.you can access that varible from react component using mapStateToProps

Comment: absolutely,you need to use redux

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your `email` state to a `common` parent of your `Login` and `User` component or use context api which you can read about it in the [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), the hardest path to achieve what you have in mind is using redux which is a state management